# Linear-gradient overlay on Bootstrap 4 gallery images

Tags: html, css, overlay, linear-gradients

I've created an image gallery using Bootstrap grid with figure and fig-caption tags, and overlaid each image with the caption text. Now I'd like to darken each image and make the text more visible. I know how to do this with a single background image, but I can't work out how to manage it for every image in my grid. My links to image srcs are in the HTML, so I haven't been able to use the background-image property on the image link in CSS, as I have previously. Do I need to change my set-up and link to images in the CSS, or can it be done with my images in HTML?

Thus far I've set a linear-gradient to the background property of the images, but that only puts the gradient behind the images.

Example of the code that works for background images:

```css
#hero-image {

    background-image:linear-gradient(rgb(60, 60, 60), rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.5)), url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/09/09/15/edinburgh-2297668_1280.jpg");
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    
}

@media only screen and (min-width:600px) {
    #hero-image {
     background-image:linear-gradient(rgb(103, 98, 98), rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.5)), url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/04/22/08/58/edinburgh-4146031_1280.jpg");
    }
}
```

```html
    <div id="hero-image">
         <div class="hero-text-box">
                <h1>Literary Edinburgh</h1> 
                <h4>Scotland's capital in books</h4> 
                <button id="hero-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg .btn-block">Get me reading!</button> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show the code that worked, HTML, CSS, and how you attempted to solve this.

Comment: @iAmOren Thanks. I've updated accordingly.

Comment: I've found something and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just got a suggestion from a course tutor that's working really well for me so sharing it here.

I've now used the filter property and set its value to brightness(50%). So the CSS rule I applied to my images is:

filter: brightness(50%);

Answer (score 0):

Found this - might help:

```
.outline-font {
  color: yellow;
  text-shadow:
   -1px -1px 0 black,  
    1px -1px 0 black,
    -1px 1px 0 black,
     1px 1px 0 black;
}
```

use:

```
<h1 class="outline-font">I'm yellow font with black outline!</h1>
```

play with the colors and "widths", look up "text-shadow", good luck!

Comment: Well, did it help?  If so, please select and up-vote my answer, thanks!